# Rotate a 2d matrix to the right

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, rotation

I want a 2d matrix to rotate to the right, it compiles fine but when I try to the run it says that the *array index is out of bounds exception*. For example, I want `{{10,20,30},{40,50,60}}` to rotate into `{{40,10},{50,20},{60,30}}`:

```java
public static int[][] rotate(int[][] m) {
    int[][] rotateM = new int[m[0].length][m.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
            rotateM[i][j] = m[j][m.length - i - 1];
        }
    }
    return rotateM;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] m = {
            {10, 20, 30},
            {40, 50, 60}};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotate(m)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

```java
private int[][] rotateMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    int backupH = h;
    int backupW = w;
    w = backupH;
    h = backupW;
    int[][] ret = new int[h][w];
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
            ret[i][j] = matrix[w - j - 1][i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I used this code to rotate my bricks in Tetris.
This code rotates the matrix clockwise.

Comment: Yes, I though for two minutes and I think it rotates to the right, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just had your indexes reversed.

Instead of:

```
rotateM[i][j] = m[j][m.length-i-1];
```

You should have written:

```
rotateM[j][i] = m[m.length-i-1][j];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't increment using `i = i++`. Just write `i++`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove that `i = i++`.

`i++` and `j++` will suffice, initialize your arrays and you have your logic wrong:

```java
for (int j = 0; j < m[0].Length; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
        rotateM[j][i] = m[m.Length - i - 1][j];
```

That is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you transpose a matrix, every its cell `[i][j]` becomes `[j][i]`, but when you rotate a matrix 90 degrees, the indices of one of its sides become equal to *`the length of the side, minus 1, minus the current index of the side`*. Indices start at 0.

```java
int m = 2;
int n = 3;

int[][] arr1 = {{10, 20, 30}, {40, 50, 60}};
int[][] arr2 = new int[n][m];
int[][] arr3 = new int[n][m];
int[][] arr4 = new int[n][m];
```

```java
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        // matrix transpose
        arr2[j][i] = arr1[i][j];
        // turn matrix 90º clockwise ⟳
        arr3[j][m - 1 - i] = arr1[i][j];
        // turn matrix 90º anticlockwise ⟲
        arr4[n - 1 - j][i] = arr1[i][j];
    }
}
```

| original matrix | matrix transpose | turn matrix 90º ⟳ | turn matrix 90º ⟲ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ``` [10, 20, 30] [40, 50, 60] ``` | ``` [10, 40] [20, 50] [30, 60] ``` | ``` [40, 10] [50, 20] [60, 30] ``` | ``` [30, 60] [20, 50] [10, 40] ``` |

---

<sup>See also:

• [How do I rotate a matrix 90 degrees counterclockwise in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65432245/14838237)

• [Is there a way to reverse specific arrays in a multidimensional array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65383974/14838237)</sup>