# Is there a way to reverse specific arrays in a multidimensional array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I know how to generally manipulate and create a multidimensional array but I don't know all the utils and features that arrays have. I want to know is if I have a 2D array the size of `[5][4]`, can I print it where the first line is in order, second is in reverse, and the third is in order... and so on.

For example:

```
[1 2 3 4] //in order
[8 7 6 5] //reverse
[9 10 11 12] //in order
[16 15 14 13] //reverse
[17 18 19 20] //in order
```

as my teacher stated "Define a two-dimensional array of size m × n. Write a method to initialize this array with numbers from 1 to m × n in the way as below: the first row, initialize the elements from left to right; the second row, initialize from right to left; then switch order. For example, if m=5; and n = 4; the array should be initialized to:"

I’m not sure if it should be done using a temp method or some other loop method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reverse it directly. But you can have a loop and reverse the alternative rows:

```java
void reverseArray() {
    Integer[][] arr = {
            {1, 2, 3, 4},
            {5, 6, 7, 8},
            {9, 10, 11, 12},
            {13, 14, 15, 16},
            {17, 18, 19, 20}};
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(arr[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[][] arr = new int[][]{
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8},
        {9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16}};

AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(ints -> {
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(ints)
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
            .reduce((a, b) ->
                    counter.get() % 2 == 0 ? a + " " + b : b + " " + a).get());
    counter.incrementAndGet();
});
```

This code uses the Stream API to iterate over an array. The first stream iterates over single-level arrays, the second - their elements, and then forms a string. Also, according to the counter value, items are combined from left to right or from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

You can create such an array with a *"snake order"* without sorting at all, using *a stream in a stream* or *a loop in a loop*:

---

1. ```java
   int m = 5;
   int n = 4;

   int[][] arr = IntStream
           // create rows of array
           .range(0, m).mapToObj(row -> IntStream
                   // for each row create cells where
                   // values are numbers from 1 to [m * n]
                   .range(0, n).map(cell -> {
                       int val = row * n;
                       if (row % 2 == 0)
                           // even rows:
                           // straight order
                           val += cell + 1;
                       else
                           // odd rows:
                           // reverse order
                           val += n - cell;
                       return val;
                   })
                   // return int[] array
                   .toArray())
           // return int[][] 2d array
           .toArray(int[][]::new);
   ```

---

2. ```java
   int m = 5;
   int n = 4;

   int[][] arr = new int[m][n];

   // create rows of array
   for (int row = 0; row < m; row++) {
       // for each row create cells where
       // values are numbers from 1 to [m * n]
       for (int cell = 0; cell < n; cell++) {
           int val = row * n;
           if (row % 2 == 0)
               // even rows:
               // straight order
               val += cell + 1;
           else
               // odd rows:
               // reverse order
               val += n - cell;
           arr[row][cell] = val;
       }
   }
   ```

---

```java
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
// [8, 7, 6, 5]
// [9, 10, 11, 12]
// [16, 15, 14, 13]
// [17, 18, 19, 20]
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [How do I rotate a matrix 90 degrees counterclockwise in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65432245/14838237)

• [Is there any other way to remove all whitespaces in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65382822/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> if I have a 2D array the size of [5][4], can I print it where the
> first line is in order, second is in reverse, and the third is in
> order... and so on.

It's unclear how you want to use the output, but here is a literal way to do it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] values = new int[][]{
            {1, 2, 3, 4},
            {5, 6, 7, 8},
            {9, 10, 11, 12},
            {13, 14, 15, 16}
    };

    for (int r = 0; r < values.length; r++) {
        if (r % 2 == 0) {
            // forwards
            for (int c = 0; c < (values[r].length - 1); c++) {
                System.out.print(values[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(values[r][values[r].length - 1]);
        } else {
            // backwards
            for (int c = (values[r].length - 1); c > 0; c--) {
                System.out.print(values[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(values[r][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
8 7 6 5
9 10 11 12
16 15 14 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as efficient as nested loops, one can simply iterator from 1 to 20 and determine row `i` and column `j`.

```
final int M = 5;
final int N = 4;
int[][] matrix = new int[M][N];

IntStream.range(0, M*N)
    .forEach(no -> { // no = 0, 1, 2, ... , M*N-1
        int i = no / N; // Row.
        int j = no % N; // Increasing column (for even row).
        if (i % 2 == 1) { // Odd row.
           j = N - 1 - j; // Decreasing column.
        }
        matrix[i][j] = no + 1;
    });
```

`i % 2` is the modulo 2, rest by division of 2, hence 0 for even, 1 for odd.

Or use a bit more language features:

```
IntStream.range(0, N)
    .forEach(i -> {
        int no = N * i;
        IntUnaryOperator jToValue = i % 2 == 0
            ? j -> no + 1 + j
            : j -> no + N - 1 -j;
        Arrays.setAll(matrix[i], jToValue);
    });
```

Here `Arrays.setAll(int[], (int index) -> int)` fills the array based on the index.

***About the question of there being some nice function:***

You probably saw `List.reverse`; there does not exist an `Arrays.reverse`, hence `Arrays.setAll` seems to be best. In this case where the values are increasing one theoretically could also sort all odd rows reversed. But only with a trick, and sorting costs.

It is interesting that there are so many solutions. Instead of waggling the dog's tail one can take the tail and waggle the dog.